# Getting the keys, and not the values

Tags: python, json

So I want to get the json keys and compare them with the variable `q`

Json file

```
{
  "api_key": "YOUR AUTOBUY API KEY",
  "prefix": "PREFIX FOR BOT COMMANDS (for e.x !redeem, ?claim, etc",
  "redeem_message": "Thanks for redeeming your order for {0}, I have added the ROLE_NAME_HERE role.",
  "role_id": "REPLACE THIS WITH THE ID OF THE ROLE YOU WANT TO GIVE UPON REDEEMING",
  "redeem_channel_id": "REPLACE THIS WITH THE CHANNEL ID WHERE PEOPLE CAN USE THE REDEEM COMMAND",
  "bot_token": "PUT YOUR DISCORD BOT TOKEN HERE"
}
```

Code

```
import json

def search(q):
    with open("config.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for obj in data:
            print(data[obj])
search(q="role_id")
```

Expected output: `REPLACE THIS WITH THE ID OF THE ROLE YOU WANT TO GIVE UPON REDEEMING` (cause `q = role_id` and I want it to return the value of the key)

Actual output:

```
YOUR AUTOBUY API KEY
PREFIX FOR BOT COMMANDS (for e.x !redeem, ?claim, etc
Thanks for redeeming your order for {0}, I have added the ROLE_NAME_HERE role.
REPLACE THIS WITH THE ID OF THE ROLE YOU WANT TO GIVE UPON REDEEMING
REPLACE THIS WITH THE CHANNEL ID WHERE PEOPLE CAN USE THE REDEEM COMMAND
PUT YOUR DISCORD BOT TOKEN HERE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple, no need for a `for` loop if you just need one value:

```py
import json

def search(q):
    with open("config.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        print(data[q])
search(q="role_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

below

```
data = {'A':12,'B':13}

q = 'A2'

value = data.get(q)
if value is not None:
    print(value)
else:
    print('{} not found'.format(q))
```